# Trouble connecting gcloud to MQTT bridge

Tags: mqtt, iot, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub, mosquitto

I am currently trying to connect a gcloud IoT project to the MQTT bridge to be able to publish telemetry data. I am using Mosquitto and am trying to run the `mosquitto_pub` command on a VM instance I created on gcloud compute engine. I also created a firewall rule to open port 8883 with priority 0. In full I am submitting the following command (I removed the JWT used and put  here in the code block)

```
mosquitto_pub \
--host mqtt.googleapis.com \
--port 8883 \
--id projects/telemetry-268916/locations/us-central1/registries/iotcore-registry-telemetry/devices/esp32 \
--username unused \
--pw "<my-JWT.>" \
--cafile ./roots.pem \
--tls-version tlsv1.2 \
--protocol-version mqttv311 \
--debug \
--qos 1 \
--topic /devices/esp32/events \
--message "Hello MQTT"
```

When I run this command ^ I get the following error:

```
Client projects/telemetry-268916/locations/us-central1/registries/iotcore-registry telemetry/devices/esp32 sending CONNECT
Client projects/telemetry-268916/locations/us-central1/registries/iotcore-registry-telemetry/devices/esp32 received CONNACK
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.
```

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution to this problem. I am using the root certificate and specifying the CA file so idk what is going on -- HELP!

Comment: Coincidentally, I've been using Cloud IoT too and, when I saw your question, I tried to publish and am receiving the same error. So, we're either both doing something wrong, or there's (!?) a problem with the gateway

Comment: I just checked an old post and I have a recollection that I couldn't get it work using keys and had to use certs. Are you using certs?

Comment: I tried using a certificate and it made no difference.

Comment: I did not try using certs. Hmm, weird. I really don't know what's going on. I tried running the command as root and now I'm getting a different error `Error: Problem setting TLS options.` This error seems ambiguous, I've seen other posts that suggest this has to do with not being able to read the CA file but I don't think that's the issue/don't know how to diagnose that.

Comment: Aha! How long is your JWT expiry? Mine was 48h and it did not work. I created another with a reduced expiry (24h) and it's working.

Comment: In fact, it would appear that any expiry>24h, fails.

Comment: Mine is <24hr. I was still getting those errors. Maybe it still is an issue with the JWT generation though.

Comment: https://github.com/Nilhcem/esp32-cloud-iot-core-k8s/blob/master/04-generate-jwt/main.py

Comment: I'm using the above repo to generate my JWT. In the code it establishes the expiration to be 60 minutes after the token is generate so idk why it's not working.

Comment: OK. Curiosity continues to be piqued. Would you be willing to provide me with an ES256 public (!) key of one of your devices? I'll add it to my registry and you can try hitting my registry. Additionally, I can give you a ES256 public key for one of my devices and try hitting your registry

Comment: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE5jtAHuxTGRBMz68bbQekxjuSOBvO
TQ3Zwds8FVOhIMMaFYfXn7mL/XZdHHWyctuhp2w7ZOGd8Jp3IqhRvu8Bkg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's that your JWT expiry is too far (>=24h) in the future.

Google Cloud IoT's MQTT gateway (documented: [the maximum lifetime of a token](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts))

to require JWTs to be <=24h

```sh
PROJECT=
REGISTRY=
REGION=
DEVICE=

CLIENT="projects/${PROJECT}/locations/${REGION}/registries/${REGISTRY}/devices/${DEVICE}"
TOPIC="/devices/${DEVICE}/events"

# Using a JWT generator; expiry=24h
PASSWORD=$(\
  go-jwt \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --private_key=${KEY} \
  --expiry=24h)

docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--volume=${PWD}/roots.pem:/roots.pem \
eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.8 mosquitto_pub \
  -h mqtt.googleapis.com -p 8883 \
  -i ${CLIENT} \
  -u unused -P ${PASSWORD} \
  -t ${TOPIC} \
  -m "Hello Freddie!" \
  --cafile /roots.pem \
  --debug \
  --qos 1 \
  --tls-version tlsv1.2 \
  --protocol-version mqttv311
sending CONNECT
received CONNACK (0)
sending PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1, '/devices/.../events', ... (14 bytes))
received PUBACK (Mid: 1, RC:0)
sending DISCONNECT

# Using a JWT generator; expiry=25h
PASSWORD=$(\
  go-jwt \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --private_key=${KEY} \
  --expiry=25h)

docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--volume=${PWD}/roots.pem:/roots.pem \
eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.8 mosquitto_pub \
  -h mqtt.googleapis.com -p 8883 \
  -i ${CLIENT} \
  -u unused -P ${PASSWORD} \
  -t ${TOPIC}
  -m "Hello Freddie!" \
  --cafile /roots.pem \
  --debug \
  --qos 1 \
  --tls-version tlsv1.2 \
  --protocol-version mqttv311
CONNECT
CONNACK (4)
Connection error: Connection Refused: bad user name or password.
DISCONNECT
```